# How to sync Notes app between iPad and Mac?

Tags: macos, ios

My Notes in iPad do not sync with Notes in my MacBook Air. How can I fix this? I'm on El Capitan. The answers I could find online are old and did not solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: iDevices must be on iOS 9 to sync with el capitan.

Comment: My iPad is running 9.1. But still does not sync.